# razor: get bytearray of <img> in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, razor

Say i have an image created from js

```
const image = document.createElement('img');
```

and I add a picture the user picked to the img:

```
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

How would I access this image and its bytes in my controller?
This is what I usuall do to get form elements:

```
       public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostButton_Login(IFormCollection data)
       {
           var firmenname = Request.Form["firmenname"];
           
            return RedirectToPage("Unternehmensprofil_2");

        }
```

Any help would be greatly!

Comment: The controller is uses to send/receive HTTP request/response.  The IActionResult is serialized data that goes into the body of the request/response.  You do not need to create an image.  You can just read the file as bytes.  Use File.ReadAllBytes(path).  The serialized data could just be Convert  Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])  Or just create a class with a property byte[]

Comment: I create the image in the frontend, so it has to be created. But eitherway, can you give me an example of how you deseriazlied the response?

Comment: See if this helps : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/612a3492-d1f0-4d25-ab70-13e0e303ce16/passing-base64-string-to-web-api?forum=aspwebapi&force_isolation=true